# Populate Excel VB array with range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an (2,100) array in Excel VB.

I'd like to populate it with two cell ranges, like:

```
MyArray(1, i) = Range("a1:a100").Value
MyArray(2, i) = Range("x1:x100").Value
```

Clearly that code won't work and is just for illustration. How should I go about pulling those two cell ranges into my array?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i = 1 to 100
    MyArray(1, i) = Range("A" & i).Value
    MyArray(2, i) = Range("X" & i).Value
next i
```

Comment: thanks. However, I was hoping for a solution that allowed me to pass the ranges as variables. My ranges won't always be in col A and X, or in rows 1 to 100.